# Need help to JOIN two CSV files

Tags: csv, join

I need some guidance on how I can do this. So, I have two CSV files. In both of those CSV files there is a phone number column. I want to conjoin all the lines that have the same phone number from both files together. For example:

File 1:

```
David Testington, 7965848344, male
Samuel Davidton, 7948574353, male
Francis Doodleton, 7954574544, female
```

File 2:

```
7954574544, landline
7948574353, mobile
7965848344, page
```

Desired output:

```
David Testington, 7965848344, male, 7965848344, page
Samuel Davidton, 7948574353, male, 7948574353, mobile
Francis Doodleton, 7954574544, female, 7954574544, landline
```

Is there anyway to do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-the-matching-of-two-columns - use awk

Answer (score 1):

You could use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

First clean your input files (you have wrong whitespaces `, 7965848344,` and not `,7965848344,`)

```
mlr -I --csv -N clean-whitespace input1 input2
```

Then to join them, run

```
mlr --csv -N join -j 2 -l 2 -r 1 --lp l --rp r -f input1 then reorder -f l1 input2 >output
```

to have

```
+-------------------+------------+--------+----------+
| Francis Doodleton | 7954574544 | female | landline |
| Samuel Davidton   | 7948574353 | male   | mobile   |
| David Testington  | 7965848344 | male   | page     |
+-------------------+------------+--------+----------+
```